# JavaFX how to combine more EventHandlers in one registration form?

Tags: java, forms, javafx

I am making registration form in JavaFX. And i have button to submit entered data, which works perfectly. But i also want to allow user to submit data when user press enter ?

Is there any way to combine in one if statement if button is pressed or enter is pressed ?

I know i can make it separately but then i need to double my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to listen to key press events and button press events separately, there is no way to handle these two events with a single listener: the button press will fire an `ActionEvent` and the key press will file a `KeyEvent`.

But, if you create a method to make the "data submission" and you simply call this method in the two listeners, you can avoid code duplication.

```
submitButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        submitData();
    }
});

scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        switch (ke.getCode()) {
            case ENTER:
                submitData();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
 }});
```

Or the same in a short form using lambdas:

```
submitButton.setOnAction(event -> submitData());
scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    if(keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
        submitData();
});
```

Comment: I understand your code, but i am begginer in javaFx so i never used methods in handle. Could you please give me example of this submitData() method ?

Comment: In the original question you said: "And i have button to submit entered data, which works perfectly.". So you entered some code in the "public void handle(ActionEvent event)" of your button. You just have to make a private method "submitData()" and copy your existing code from handle to this method. If you edit the question to include the original code to handle button press I will update the answer for you.