# How to make method which will handle events?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Pane p = new Pane();
    p.setPrefSize(400, 300);
    Button btn = new Button("Submit");
    btn.relocate(10, 10);

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.relocate(10, 40);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            text = tf.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    });

    btn.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
                text = tf.getText();

            System.out.println(text);
        }
    });

    p.getChildren().addAll(btn,tf);
    Scene sc = new Scene(p);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Here is my code. As you can see i have two EventHandlers. One which check if enter is pressed and the other one which check if button is pressed. My goal is to make one method and whenever one of these two EventHandlers activate it takes input from TextFields.

In this example i have only one TextField but in my application i have plenty of them so if i do the same thing in two EventHandlers i will double my code. I guess there is option to make method which will do that for me.

Comment: If all you want is a method to do the action of both listeners, then have you tried making a method that gets the text of the TextField and prints it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX how to combine more EventHandlers in one registration form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236478/javafx-how-to-combine-more-eventhandlers-in-one-registration-form)

Comment: You may edit your old question with code. Please do not repost

Comment: It is not the same, here i am asking for the method :)

Comment: And the person who answered you both here and there was willing to edit the answer to show you the method

Comment: In the end, I guess your problem(s) is solved. So could you accept and vote-up the answer (on this question and on the other one) which you like most to close this topic(s)? And next time please edit the question as I asked, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to make one method and whenever one of these two EventHandlers activate it takes input from TextFields.
>
> In this example i have only one TextField but in my application i have plenty of them

If the goal is a method, then make a method. If you have many text fields and want to do a similar action for them in any handle method, then use a parameter.

```
public void printTextField(TextField tf)
{
    System.out.println(tf.getText());
}
```

Anywhere in your code, (e.g. In the event handlers) you can now call

```
printTextField(tf);
```